# How to find the kernel of linear operator $L(p(x)) = xp'(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

My notes say that the kernel is similar to the null space. I tried it with a particular example and I kind of understood it until the end:

The domain is $P^3=\{ax^2+bx+c\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}.$

I have given the linear operator $L$, which acts on $P^3$ as follows:

$$L(p(x)) = xp'(x)$$

$$= x(2ax + b)$$

$$= 2ax^2 +bx.$$

Setting it equal to $0$, I get $2a =b = 0$ as the only solution.

Then I get $\text{ker}(L) = P^1,$ where $P^1=\{c\mid c\in\mathbb{R}\}$ are the constant polynomials. We can say that the basis of the kernel is $\{1\}=\{x^0\}$.

But I'm not sure why that is the case.

Comment: What's the domain of $L$, and what is $P1(x)$?

Comment: Oops, forgot to add it. It's $P^3$. And P1(x) represents all polynomials of degree 0, so I guess it basically means all constants.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the kernel *is* equal to the null space in the case of linear operators. The kernel is the set of polynomials $p(x)$ that map to $0$ under $L$, but the null space is similarly the space of polynomials $p(x)$ that map to $0$. The two concepts are equal.

You want to find the kernel of $L$, which is the same as finding the null space. You are trying to figure out for which second-degree polynomials $p(x)$ we have $L(p(x)) = 0$, and you've derived that this happens only when $p(x)=c$ (a constant).

But $c$ can be any constant, which means that the set of $p(x)$ for which $L(p(x))=0$ is $\{c|c\in\mathbb{R}\}$, and this is exactly the definition of the null space/kernel. In short:

$$\text{Null}(L) = \{p(x)\in P^3\ |\ L(p(x)) = 0\} = \{ax^2+bx+c\ |\ a=b=0\}=P^1,$$
where you intepret this $P^1$ as the subspace of constants in $P^3$.

Answer (score 1):

One can think about this intuitively, but I think it is perfectly acceptable to just slam this into the matrix methods taught throughout a standard Linear algebra course. We can pick an ordered basis for $P^3$. I will choose $\{p_1=1, p_2=x, p_3=x^2\}$.

We can compute the images of these basis vectors directly: \begin{align*}L(p_1(x))&=x\cdot 0=0\\ L(p_2(x))&=x\cdot 1=x\\ L(p_3(x))&=x\cdot 2x=2x^2.\\\end{align*} Thus we have that the matrix of $L$ with respect to the chosen basis is 
\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
It was said above that the null space and the kernel are the same thing. This is basically true, but there is a distinction in practice. We can talk about the null-space of a $\textbf{matrix}$ as the set of vectors that when multiplied by the matrix give the zero vector. The kernel of a $\textbf{Linear transformation}$ is the set of vectors in the domain that are mapped to zero via the transformation. It is only when we select a basis that we can construct a matrix representing our linear transformation, and identify the null-space of that matrix with the kernel of the linear transformation. With that understood we can compute the kernel as the null-space of the above matrix.

If we consider multiplying a vector by the above matrix, we recover
\begin{equation*}
A \begin{bmatrix}
c \\
b \\
a
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where c,b, and a are chosen to correspond with the coefficients of the polynomials defined as you defined the domain, $P^3$. One can see immediately that this multiplication yields the zero vector if and only if $b=0$ and $a=0$ because the matrix is diagonal.